# How do I append two attributed strings with different fonts?

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uikit, nsattributedstring

Here I have tried to append two attributed strings in a single `UILabel` but I made some mistake so any one can find my mistake please?

```
let textFontAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName : font,
            // Note: SKColor.whiteColor().CGColor breaks this
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
            NSStrokeColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
            // Note: Use negative value here if you want foreground color to show
            NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: -8]
```

Comment: Can you please provide more info of what is wrong? Or what error are you getting?

Comment: It doesn't show any error at my end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the demo, you can have a try, In fact, you should provide more info of what the wrong is or what the error is.

```
var firstString  = "Hello" as NSString

var secondString = " World"  as NSString

var totalString = firstString.stringByAppendingString(secondString as String) as NSString

let firsttAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16),
    // Note: SKColor.whiteColor().CGColor breaks this
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
    NSStrokeColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
    // Note: Use negative value here if you want foreground color to show
    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: -8]

let secondAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12),
    // Note: SKColor.whiteColor().CGColor breaks this
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor(),
    NSStrokeColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
    // Note: Use negative value here if you want foreground color to show
    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName: -8]

var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: totalString as String, attributes: firsttAttributes)

var secondRange = totalString.rangeOfString(secondString as String)

if secondRange.location != NSNotFound {
    attributedString.addAttributes(secondAttributes, range: secondRange)
}
```